# report for purchased Kindle material?

Tags: kindle, amazon, kindle-app, free, history

How do I see only purchased items with a value greater than zero?

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-view-my-all-time-Kindle-purchase-history

shows all "purchased" items, including free material.  A spreadsheet would be preferable.